# Source for Arizal’s teaching

Tags: sources-mekorot, jewish-books, mysticism-kabbalah, middos-character-traits, arizal

I’m reading a book by Rabbi Shlomo Arush and he says the following: "According to our master, the Arizal, whoever wants to receive the light of Ein Sof in its entirety has to change its own nature from one of "receiving" to one of "giving"."

I have also seen many other quote this idea of changing one’s nature from "receiving" to "giving" and attributing it to the Arizal.

However, I have never found any source in the Arizal (or in classical Kabbalah texts altogether) that says so. So this is my question: can you please give me the exact source (book, chapter, page) where the Arizal talks about stop being a "receiver" and becoming a "giver"?

BEST REGARDS

Comment: Welcome to Mi Yodeya! I’ve taken the liberty of adding relevant tags to your post; if you would rather not have them, feel free to roll back my edit. Hope to see you around.

Comment: Ezra, I’m reading שעריו בתודה - בגן התודה. Garden of Gratitude.

Comment: @Yehonathan - Ah, a good one. By the way, since you're new to M''Y you might not know this, but put an "@" before someone's username so that they'll be notified that you replied to their comment.